# Counting length of another object property within object function -- JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am new to JavaScript objects so please bear with me.

This is my JavaScript:

```
var dragSources = {
  elementSources: {
    squareSource: document.getElementById('squareSource'),
    circleSource: document.getElementById('circleSource')
  },
  ifDragSource: function(elem) {
    console.log(this.elementSources.length);
  }
};
```

If you look at `console.log(this.elementSources.length);` you can probably tell that I am trying to get the length of the `elementSources` property. However, it returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an object, not an array, therefore it doesn't have a `length` property.

You could use `Object.keys(this.elementSources).length` to get the number of keys.

The [`.keys()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) essentially returns an array of the object's keys.

In this case, `Object.keys(this.elementSources)` returns:

```
["squareSource", "circleSource"]
```

Then we are just getting the length of that array, which is 2.

```js
var dragSources = {
  elementSources: {
    squareSource: document.getElementById('squareSource'),
    circleSource: document.getElementById('circleSource')
  },
  ifDragSource: function(elem) {
    console.log(Object.keys(this.elementSources).length);
  }
};

dragSources.ifDragSource(); // 2
```

Comment: Awesome! I'll implement it and see if it works :)

Comment: It works, I'll accept your answer in 10 minutes :)

Comment: Could you also explain what the `Object.keys` function does too :) I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Technically if you need the length property in a code you have to store the length value directly in the object. 
Using Object.key function decreases the code efficiency .
every time you invoke that function to access that value you have to re-run the same function again and again.

in order access to the length property in a js array, the **BIG O** is always equal to 1.
 because when you update the array the length property would be updated consequently
But in that case the big O would be in the size of the Object and **(O) = n**